# Wait for a function to finish before starting next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, wait

Probably a very simple question, but I'm a JavaScript newbie:

How do I wait for the "mouseenter" animation to be finished before starting the "mouseleave" animation?

Sometimes the mouse movement of the user is very quick but I want that animation to play completely mouseleave action is called.

```
$('.footer-links').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('.footer-links').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS `transition` or `animation` use the respective `"transitionend"` or `"animationend"` events:

To keep the hover state whilst hovered, move the `"transitionend"` callback inside the `"mouseleave"` Event and make sure to use in CSS both the `:hover` and the *class* `.hover` together!

```js
$('.footer-links').on({
  mouseenter() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  },
  mouseleave() {
    $(this).on("transitionend", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.footer-links {
  transition: background 2s ease-out;
}

.footer-links:hover,
.footer-links.hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">TEST ONE</div>
<div class="footer-links">TEST TWO</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, could work very well in some instance, but i would need the "hover" state to stay while the user is hovering. When i'm testing your code, the "hover" class is removed as soon as the animation is over

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier Add it inside the `"mouseleave"` event - I'll edit my answer. Happy coding!

Comment: The "mouseleave" doesn't seem to be working for me :(
Here's my test: https://nolk-ae69bb.webflow.io/test-add-class

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier In your demo you're toggling some `"onhover"` classes, but I cannot see any `.onhover` in your CSS. Does the example I posted above works? If yes - than make sure to implement all its parts :)

Comment: weird, it seems to be working when the transition is set to 1second or more. It doesn't work with quick transitions (Im trying 200ms)

Answer (score -2):

You need to bind kind of events for checking css animation.

```
el.addEventListener("animationstart", function() {}, false);
el.addEventListener("animationend", function() {}, false);
el.addEventListener("animationiteration", function() {}, false);
```

You can add appropriate profixed-events as well like `webkitAnimationEnd`